# Get attribute of target and not parent in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, attributes, event-listener

I have a `forEach` loop that gets the attribute of any element that has the specified attribute on my page. It looks something like this:

```
const cursorActionElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-cursor]");

cursorActionElements.forEach((el) => {
 const elAttr = el.getAttribute("data-cursor");

 el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   console.log(elAttr)
 });
});
```

It all works fine. It goes through and gets all elements that have the `data-cursor` attribute and stores its value in the `elAttr` variable. However, for some reason, If the parent of the target happens to *ALSO* have a `data-cursor` attribute, it returns both the target's `data-cursor` value, *AND* its parent's `data-cursor` value.

I'm really not sure how to solve this issue. I've thought of retrieving the `data-cursor` value on `mouseover` but, that just means I need to use yet *another* event listner and it seems to slow my site down a bit.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the event is propagating up the DOM from the child to the parent, so the event handler fires once per element. To fix this you can call `stopPropagation()` on the event passed to the event handler.

Also note that it would be a better idea to read the `data` attribute from the Event object as well, to avoid any scope/closure issues which may arise when relying on the variable set in a loop within an event handler.

Here's a working example with the above changes made:

```js
const cursorActionElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-cursor]");

cursorActionElements.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const elAttr = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-cursor");
    console.log(elAttr)
  });
});
```

```html
<div data-cursor="foo">foo</div>
<div data-cursor="bar">
  bar
  <div data-cursor="foobar">
    foobar
  </div>
  <div>
    no data attribute
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's an issue though. With the `mouseover` event, it gets interupted by the target's children even if they don't have a `data-cursor` attribute.

Comment: @jos3ph_1205 you're right - I've updated `e.target` to `e.currentTarget` to fix that

Answer (score 0):

This is because the  `mouseover` event bubbles up the DOM tree, which means it triggers on the parent element when you hover over a child element. To solve this issue, you can use the `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`.

```js
const cursorActionElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-cursor]");

cursorActionElements.forEach((el) => {
  const elAttr = el.getAttribute("data-cursor");

  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    console.log(elAttr);
  });
});
```

Now, when you hover over an element with the `data-cursor` attribute, it will only log the value of that attribute, not the value of any parent elements.

Comment: Thanks @jos3ph_1205 i am glad you found my answer helpful. Both my and RoryMcCrossan s answer have approach the problem slightly diff.

Using mouseenter event ensures that the event listener only triggers when the mouse enters the specific element with the data-cursor it is having advantage if you want to specifically target the behaviour of the particular elements and ofcourse performance isn't a big concern for you but, On the other hand,  using mouseover event with e.stopPropagation() is effective in preventing or stoping  the DOM tree

Comment: There's an issue though. For some reason, with the `mouseover` event, it gets interupted by the target's children even if they don't have a `data-cursor` attribute. If I use `mouseenter`, the `elAttr` variable doenst update if I move my cursor from one if the target's children, back to the target.

Comment: If you are going with the mouseover event and facing this issue you might need a slightly different approach

Comment: Best is to go with the 'mouseenter' or try using both 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave' events then define 'elAttr' outside the event listeners after that update 'elAttr' only if the target has the attribute

then in 'mouseleave' event reset the 'elAttr = null'